# How to create a summary table with multiple levels for each variable?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a summary table like the ones that are seen in research papers. I am struggling with trying to create multiple levels for each of the variables I am including in the table.

I want my table to have 4 columns: Variables (eg. Sex, Age, Race, etc), Levels Treatment 1, & Treatment 2.

So I want the first row under the variable column to be Sex and then underneath the Level column I want it to say Male and Female. Then the next column would read how many patients are male in treatment 1 and treatment 2, etc.

I'm not really sure where to begin and whether I should do this in R markdown or in a normal script.

Here's a reproducible example and I also include how I want the final result to look like as well. Thanks in advance!

```
tab <- data.frame("Sex" = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Female"), 
                  "Treatment" = c(1,2,1, 2),
                  "Number" = c(59,43,23,20))
```

```
Variable      Levels    Treatment 1      Treatment 2 
Sex            Male         59                 23
              Female        43                 20

Age            Mean        ...                ...
                SD         ...                ...

Race           White       ...                ...
               Black       ...                ...

ETC
```

Comment: This is not a proper reproducible example. If we need to summarise on different variables, please provide a dataset with multiple variables. Please include at least the age and RAce variable values

Comment: It’s fine if the sex variable can be done. I’ll figure out the other variables by using the solution from this post.

Comment: Have a look at the `gtsummary` package which is meant to create nice summary tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `gtsummary` library to do this.

First we create a dummy dataset to demonstrate.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

# Create dummy dataset (50 cases).

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  Sex = sample(c("Female", "Male"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Age = sample(18:80, 50, replace = TRUE),
  Race = sample(c("White", "Black"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Income = sample(c("High", "Low"), 50, replace = TRUE),
  Treatment1 = sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE),
  Treatment2 = sample(0:1, 50, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Then we can use the `tbl_strata` function in `gtsummary` to create a summary table with the levels you want.

```
table <- df %>%
  tbl_strata(
  strata = c("Treatment1", "Treatment2"),
  ~ .x %>%
    tbl_summary(
      type = list(
        Age ~ "continuous",
        Sex ~ "categorical",
        Race ~ "categorical",
        Income ~ "categorical"
      ),
      statistic = list(
          Age ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
          all_categorical() ~ "{n}"
        )
    )
  )
```

I found these pages helpful: [Epidemiologist R Handbook (Descriptive Tables)](https://epirhandbook.com/en/descriptive-tables.html), [Stratified gtsummary Tables](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_strata.html).

Another approach would be to use the [table1 package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html). There the code for this example would be:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(Sex = factor(Sex, levels = c("Male", "Female")),
         Race = factor(Race, levels = c("White", "Black")),
         Income = factor(Income, levels = c("High", "Low")),
         Treatment1 = factor(Treatment1, levels = c(0, 1)),
         Treatment2 = factor(Treatment2, levels = c(0, 1)))

units(df2$Age) <- "years"
```

```
table1(~ factor(Sex) + Age + factor(Race) + factor(Income) | Treatment1, data = df2, overall = FALSE)
```

`table1` also supports stratification with two variables using the format x*y e.g. `table1(~ factor(Sex) + Age + factor(Race) + factor(Income) | Treatment1*Treatment2)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I believe the table1 package will help me get to the solution I am looking for.